# How to use background-position and background-size in CSS but also anchor an image at a certain point

Tags: html, css, image, background-position

I have a layout that looks like this, from using `background-position: center` and `background-size: cover`:

[image]

The original image is from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama):

[image: Obama]

I would like for the first example to look more like this:

[image]

To do this I am imagining putting an anchor point on the image and somehow telling CSS to use this anchor point.

```
background-position: x y;
```

Wondering how I could accomplish this.

I don't want to crop the image, as when the screen is resized, or on mobile for example, it will show more of the image. I want the image to be as is. I also don't want the image squished, I want it to work like `background-size: cover` works roughly, but with a custom anchor point.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the element that is supposed to get the background-image ?

Comment: The dimensions are arbitrary, it could be in this case `flex: 1`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979628/how-to-layout-image-so-it-is-to-left-of-ad-space-and-yet-centered-using-flexbox) is the layout roughly.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include _the shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself**_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: add `background-position:top center`

Answer (score 0):

```
div.relative {
   background: url(mountain.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: auto;
   position: relative
   top: //what you want  e.g. 20px
   left: //e.g. 40px;
   bottom: //e.g. 80px;
   right: //e.g. 0px;
}
```